# AS2 check if external file is loaded

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

First, yes I know AS2 is outdated, but I'm self taught and AS2 was easier to learn. Since I started this project I've began moving on to AS3, but I really don't want to try to recode this project into AS3.

So, the question.
I'm using a shell swf that loads in another swf that's hosted on a different site. I'd like to be able to test if the external swf successfully loaded, and if not then to attempt to load it from a backup host. Is there a way to do that?

Here is the shell's code (works just fine, just want to add an if/else test to it):

```
    stop();

    this.onEnterFrame=function(){
        var mc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
        var image:MovieClip = mc.createEmptyMovieClip("image", mc.getNextHighestDepth());
        image.loadMovie("[redacted]");
        image._lockroot = true;
        delete this.onEnterFrame;
    }
```

I tried running an image.getBytesTotal() after the image.loadMovie(), but it always kicks back a 0 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution. Switched to using MovieClipLoader.loadClip() instead of loadMovie() and called an onLoadError listener.

Here the code that works if anyone else is trying to do similar, it test the 1st host, loads a backup, then tests that host too, if both fail then it advances by shell clip to a frame that holds an error message for the viewer.

```
    var container:MovieClip = createEmptyMovieClip("container", getNextHighestDepth());
    var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
    mcLoader.addListener(this);
    mcLoader.loadClip("URL", container);
    container._lockroot = true;


    var mclListener:Object = new Object(); 
    mclListener.onLoadError = function(target_mc:MovieClip, errorCode:String) { 
        if(errorCode == 'URLNotFound'){
            mcLoader.loadClip("URL", container);
            trace("host 1 failed");
            container._lockroot = true;
            mclListener.onLoadError = function(target_mc:MovieClip, errorCode:String) { 
                if(errorCode == 'URLNotFound'){
                    trace("host 2 failed");
                    _root.gotoAndStop(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }; 
    mcLoader.addListener(mclListener);

    stop();
```